# Rails cannot create even though all code same as others that worked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my well-functioning app, I created another model, Action. Every code for it is the same as the other models that save perfectly well. But when I create with it, I get this error:

```
undefined method `permit' for "create":String
```

And params in the controller is highlighted:

```
    def action_params
      params.require(:action).permit(:text)
    end
```

My create method:

```
def create
    @club = Club.find(params[:club_id])
    @action = @club.actions.build(action_params)
    @action.club_id = @club.id

        if @action.save
      redirect_to club_path(@club)
        else 
            redirect_to club_path(@club), alert: "Please make sure to type at least 1 character." 
        end
        
    end
```

Action model:

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :club
  has_many :outcomes
```

The view:

```
            <%= form_for([@user, @club, @action]) do |f| %>
                <container style="max-width:300px;display:block;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-bottom:100px;">
                <div>
                    <%= f.text_area :text, class:'uk-textarea', style:"max-height: 130px;", placeholder:'' %>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <%= f.submit "Post", class:'uk-button uk-text-capitalize', style:" margin-top:10px; " %>
                </div>
                </container>
            <% end %>
```

Routes and ability (authorization) are all same as the other models that are at the same scope.

I've tried deleting `require` from the params. It didn't work. No error, but simply did not save.

I am baffled. Please help.

params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[redacted]", "commit"=>"Post", "club_id"=>"22"}
```

Comment: Please add your params to your question. You'll see that there is a key `action` with the value `create` which is standard for your create route.

Comment: @jvillian added what I saw, but not sure if that's what you meant. I can try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you have a naming conflict with a core concept in Rails. In Rails the method called on your controller is named `action` and the params hash always contains  `controller` and `action` keys which are added to the request by the router middleware when it matches the request to a controller. This actually plasters over the incoming parameter sent by the form.

The simplest solution would be to just find another name for your model or place your model in a module which changes how [ActiveModel::Name](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Name.html) generates stuff like param keys:

```
module Foo
  class Action
    include ActiveModel::Model
  end
end

puts Foo::Action.naming.param_key # "foo_action"
```

You can also override the parameter key in a form by using the `as` option for [`form_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for):

```
<%= form_for([@user, @club, @action], as: :foo) do |f| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Or the scope option for `form_with`. But I would question if it really is a good idea to just patch over the problem as there is most likely no end to the bugs that this naming issue will generate down the line.

Comment: TLDR; Don't name your models Action or Controller unless you want to have a bad time.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. Thank you so much!